# Declaring arguments for taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, actions

Just a bugbear about declaring taxonomies, reading Justin Tadlocks article about [Taxonomies](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database)
and want to find what does the 0 mean in this snippet from the above article:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_pc_db_taxonomies', 0 );
```

In the codex article on taxonomies they've omitted it but I see it used just about on every tutorial published so far.

Lastly is there a benefit to calling the above function before the actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) is the priority, or order in which functions hooked to an action will be executed. from [`add_action` in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

> (optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>   Default: 10

omitting priority gives your action hook the default priority of 10. in the specific case of the tutorial you linked, I don't see any particular reason why it has to be given a priority of 0.

as for your other question-

> Lastly is there a benefit to calling the above function before the actual function

simply defining a function does not call that function. the snippet you posted is hooking that function to an action, in this case `init`. [from codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API):

> Actions are the hooks that the WordPress core launches at specific points during execution, or when specific events occur. Your plugin can specify that one or more of its PHP functions are executed at these points, using the Action API.

When WordPress reaches the `init` phase of a request, all functions hooked to that action will be called. See the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in codex for more info and a list of all of the actions WordPress executes in a request.